# Why is Konjunktiv used in this sentence?

Tags: subjunctive

The text I'm quoting below is a portion of an interview with the Austrian historian Manfried Rauchensteiner about Franz Joseph I of Austria (1830-1916). The interview appears in the article "[Der Kaiser wollte Krieg - aber keinen Weltkrieg](http://www.sueddeutsche.de/politik/franz-joseph-i-der-kaiser-wollte-krieg-aber-keinen-weltkrieg-1.3259612)" from *The Süddeutsche Zeitung*.

My question relates to the second sentence in the below paragraph: Why is Konjunktiv (ausgetrickst worden wäre) used there? To me *ausgetrickst worden war* seems more appropriate.

> *[REPORTER] War auch der Ausbruch des Ersten Weltkrieges eine bewusste Entscheidung des Kaisers?*
>
> [HISTORIAN] Franz Joseph war zweifellos derjenige, der den Weg in den Krieg
>   freigemacht hat. **Es ist ein Ammenmärchen, dass der Kaiser von
>   kriegslüsternen Militärs und Politikern ausgetrickst worden *wäre*.** Ende
>   Juli 1914 wurde dem Kaiser vom Minister des Äußeren ein umfangreicher
>   Akt zum Konflikt mit Serbien vorgelegt. Dazu schrieb Franz Joseph in
>   gestochener Handschrift ausführlich dazu, dass er den Minister
>   ermächtigt, die Kriegserklärung an das Königreich Serbien
>   abzuschicken.

Answer (score 8):

Konjunktiv 2 indicates irrealis. As the word ›Ammenmärchen‹ already tells you, the following subordinate clause contains information which is considered untrue by the author.

Another example:

> Seit langem glaubt man, ich wäre ein Idiot (aber ich bin keiner).

With the noun ›Ammenmärchen‹ already making the following untrue, the irreal Konjunktiv form however is a little over the top.

Comment: So, "ausgetrickst worden war" would also be grammatically correct here, instead of "ausgetrickst worden wäre"?

Comment: Yes. Wouldn't use the Plusquamperfekt, though. It'd be ›ausgetrickst wurde‹.

Comment: Using the Indikativ in this situation was still considered incorrect (but OK in informal situations) when I went to school in the 1990s. We were only given the choice between Konjunktiv 2 and Konjunktiv 1.

Comment: If there's no quotation in sight, Konjunktiv 1 isn't used very frequently anymore.

Comment: By the way, back then wenn-sentences were _würdelos_. A teacher of mine once marked the _täte_ in ›…, wenn sie dasselbe täte‹.